# Implementing IdentityServer4 security on SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, identityserver4

We have a SPA built on Angular and WebApi Dotnet Core. This application is using IdentityServer4 for authentication and authorization. We want to integrate Sql Reporting Services reports inside it. How can we secure these reports with the IdentityServer4?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Has this been progressed at all?

Comment: @stoneMaster did u find and solution ?

Comment: @Jek Yes, we were able to get it working, but I couldn't share the solution because my company considered it proprietary. There was a very helpful post that helped us out on the IdentityServer4 git forum.